# Cannot convert the JSON object to POJO using GSON (on Android)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have the following method in the controller:

```
public class FoundController {

private JSONObject accessPoint;
private JSONArray accessPoints;
private List<WlanNetwork> accessPointlist;
private Gson gson;

public FoundController() {
    this.accessPoint = new JSONObject();
    this.accessPoints = new JSONArray();
    this.accessPointlist = new ArrayList<>();
    this.gson = new Gson();
}


public List<WlanNetwork> getFoundWlanNetworks() {
    accessPoints = CommonHelper.getWifiList(Constants.Global.FILE_WPA_SUPLICANT_CONF);
    accessPointlist = new ArrayList<WlanNetwork>();

    for (int i = 0; i < accessPoints.length(); i++) {
        try {
            Logger.d(accessPoints.getJSONObject(i).toString());
            WlanNetwork accessPointPOJO = gson.fromJson(accessPoints.getJSONObject(i).toString(), WlanNetwork.class);
            Logger.d(accessPointPOJO.getSssid());
            accessPointlist.add(accessPointPOJO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("Exception");
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    Logger.d(String.valueOf(accessPointlist.size()));
    return accessPointlist;
}
```

}

Method:

```
accessPoints.getJSONObject(i).toString()
```

Returns:

```
 {"key_mgmt":"NONE","priority\"":"97","ssid":"test"}
```

But if i trying to convert to POJO object using the:

```
WlanNetwork accessPointPOJO = gson.fromJson(accessPoints.getJSONObject(i).toString(), WlanNetwork.class);
```

I always get the following exception:

```
No message/exception is set
```

Model class is the following:

```
public class WlanNetwork {
    private String sssid;
    private String key_mgmt;
    private String sim_slot;
    private String imsi;
    private String priority;

    public WlanNetwork(String sssid, String key_mgmt, String sim_slot, String imsi, String priority) {
        super();
        this.sssid = sssid;
        this.key_mgmt = key_mgmt;
        this.sim_slot = sim_slot;
        this.imsi = imsi;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getSssid() {
        return sssid;
    }

    public void setSssid(String sssid) {
        this.sssid = sssid;
    }

    public String getKey_mgmt() {
        return key_mgmt;
    }

    public void setKey_mgmt(String key_mgmt) {
        this.key_mgmt = key_mgmt;
    }

    public String getSim_slot() {
        return sim_slot;
    }

    public void setSim_slot(String sim_slot) {
        this.sim_slot = sim_slot;
    }

    public String getImsi() {
        return imsi;
    }

    public void setImsi(String imsi) {
        this.imsi = imsi;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

I tried almost everything but without luck. What can be Wrong please?

Many thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:**

printStackTrace returns

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 12:54:56.421  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.orhanobut.logger.LoggerPrinter.log(LoggerPrinter.java:218)
10-16 12:54:56.421  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.orhanobut.logger.LoggerPrinter.d(LoggerPrinter.java:109)
10-16 12:54:56.421  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.orhanobut.logger.Logger.d(Logger.java:49)
10-16 12:54:56.421  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.testr.controller.FoundController.getFoundWlanNetworks(FoundController.java:38)
10-16 12:54:56.421  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.testr.view.fragment.Fragment_found.processWhatIsNeed(Fragment_found.java:51)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.testr.view.fragment.Fragment_found.onActivityCreated(Fragment_found.java:76)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1970)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
10-16 12:54:56.422  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
10-16 12:54:56.423  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
10-16 12:54:56.423  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-16 12:54:56.423  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395)
10-16 12:54:56.423  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 12:54:56.423  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-16 12:54:56.423  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
10-16 12:54:56.424  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
10-16 12:54:56.424  11985-11985/com.testr W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The key in JSON is called "ssid", your field is called "sssid", it doesn't match. Is this the problem?

Comment: also i think you need `@SerializedName("ssid")` before variable `initialization`

Answer (score 0):

Check your json string. There is an extra quote and backslash near "priority" key.

```
{"key_mgmt":"NONE","priority\"":"97","ssid":"test"}
```

And also the service response key "ssid" does not match with POJO class property "sssid". Change the POJO class property name.